# Automatically provisioned tagging server no longer works for GA4 server-side tagging

Tags: server-side, google-tag-manager-server-side

Bear with me, I am not a developer, so forgive the entry-level post.

My company has used Google Cloud automatically provisioned tagging servers to set up server-side tagging for Google Analytics 4.

Until recently, the process involved:

1. Create a server-container in Google Tag Manager.
2. Create an automatically provisioned tagging server.
3. Going directly to "App Enginge" -> "Setting" and configuring a custom subdomain for the tagging server.

But now, when I create an automatically provisioned tagging server, I cannot go directly to "App Enginge" -> "Settings, Google Cloud asks me to create create an application. And I have no idea how to proceed.

I tried talking to ChatGPT, which informed me that "Google recently deprecated the automatically provisioned tagging servers" - and that's all the information I have been able to find.

I have tried creating an application (Choosing a geographical region and selecting "App engine default service account". Which does indeed create an application, leading me to a setup which looks like what i'm used to. But the end result doesn't work, when I configure my subdomain and finish the Tag Manager setup. So I must be doing something wrong.

Based on the above, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I hope someone can guide me.